# Why isn't Drupal object oriented?

Tags: 6

I just started to peek into the docs and source (Drupal 6 at the moment) and noticed that there are no classes to be seen, only vast number of prefixed functions. Is this handy? Does such decision have a background? Why?

Comment: Why are you using Drupal 6?  Drupal *8* is on the way!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is pretty well explained on [Drupal programming from an object-oriented perspective](http://drupal.org/node/547518).

In short, Drupal has existed for much longer than you could properly use OOP in PHP. Which means, [PHP5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php).

Drupal 7 already uses classes internally in a lot of places and it will probably continue so with Drupal 8.

But this is a step by step process and not everything needs to be a class. For example, it does not make any sense to make modules into a single class.

Comment: Drupal 8 will be very OOP, pulling in many of the components of Symfony2. But the APIs for developers will still be the backward-compatible hooks, FTMP.

Comment: It will be a lot more OOP yet, and the point about the API's is not correct. That's just because things aren't completely converted yet. hook_block_*() just got replaced by the plugin system, for example, routing will change, configuration will change, the entity system has changed, ...

Comment: @Berdir I am very interested in how to leverage OOP PHP in Drupal 7 as I will probably not make the move to Drupal 8 right now. Are there some examples?

Answer (score 5):

Drupal was created before oo became better in php5. Objects are being used more in drupal in each release but you need to balance a complete rewrite and adding new features.